# Dynamically change terminal window size on Win11

Tags: terminal, batch-file

I have an application that expects exact terminal window size. On Win10 I use the following batch script to start the application:

```
@echo off
mode 96, 50
py main.py
pause
```

When I used the same script on Win11 it opened PowerShell instead of Command Prompt and it kept the default terminal window size (120 x 50).

I would like to have a single batch script that when double-clicked opens the terminal at specified width and height. I do not care if I get PowerShell or Command Prompt, as long as the window size is correct.

---

I did some tests with the Terminal in Win11 and here is what I found out.

**Test 1.** Right-click in a directory and select "Open in Terminal". It opens the Win11-style terminal window as "Windows PowerShell". I can now manually open "Command Prompt" and it creates a new tab in the terminal window. I typed "mode 20" and the text in the window got all messed up, but the window size did not change.

**Test 2.** Type "cmd" in the search bar and click on "Command Prompt". Again, it opens the Win11-style terminal window but now as "Command Prompt". Same problem with "mode 20" as in Test 1.

**Test 3.** Type "cmd" in the search bar and run "Command Prompt" as Administrator. Now I got the Win10-style terminal window and the "mode" command seems to produce the desired effect.

Double-click on a .bat or .cmd file runs the script in the Win11-style terminal, which does not change its width and height.

Comment: What extension does your script-file have? If it is a .bat or a .cmd it SHOULD open with CommandPrompt (and work as expected) and should NOT open with PowerShell. Either you have misconfigured your system to open .bat or .cmd with PowerShell or you are using another extension for which PowerShell is set as handler instead of CommandPrompt as you intended. The mode command is a CommandPrompt thing and will not work as expected in PowerShell.

Comment: @Tonny I tried with .bat and .cmd, and they both run in Win11-style terminal window which does not change size. I did few other tests - I edited my original post to include what I've found out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I used the same script on Win11 it opened PowerShell instead of Command Prompt and it kept the default terminal window size (120 x 50).

`.bat` scripts are always interpreted by Command Prompt (Cmd.exe), but the actual window that you see is *neither* PowerShell nor Command Prompt – it's either Windows Terminal on Win11 or Conhost (aka just "the Windows console") on Win10.

Currently, Windows Terminal **[does not support](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094)** being resized by the console apps, neither via the Win32-style API nor via the Unix-style VT codes. (Partly because it supports tabs, and they haven't decided what to do when different tabs ask for different sizes.)

Comment: Does "Conhost" exist on Win11? From "Test 3" in my original post it seems it does. Can I somehow specify in the .bat script to run the Command Prompt in Conhost instead of Windows Terminal?

Comment: It does, there's an option somewhere in Win11 system settings (and I *think* mirrored in Windows Terminal settings, too) that lets you choose between the two. You cannot choose it per-program, as far as I know (unless you switch the system to using conhost like before, opening WT manually when wanted).

Comment: Here is a solution: In the "Windows Terminal" run the following command `conhost test.cmd` either as PowerShell or Command Prompt. This will open the conhost window which will also process the `test.cmd` script from my original post, i.e. change the conhost window size and run the Python program. It is also possible to write a wrapper in Python for the original Python program that will call conhost and process the script: `os.system('conhost test.cmd')`. I'm accepting your answer because it helped me find the solution. Please consider adding this solution to your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 5):

To be able to change the dimensions, you'll need to run the script using conhost. For windows 11 users who find cmd.exe opens in Windows terminal [the new default], the process to revert Conhost to default is:

Press the windows key
Type in cmd.exe in the search bar
Select **run as Admin**
Right click on the title bar
Select Defaults
In the Terminal Tab, select the dropbox and change the default terminal application to Windows Console host

[image: Run as Admin]
[image: Right click on title bar and select defaults]
[image: Set default to Conhost]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I still prefer the solution I wrote in a comment to user1686's post, because it does not require users to change any default settings on their operating system. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are launching your scripts in Window Terminal which isn't able to do re-sizes like the old conhost console did.
But you can still have scripts launch in conhost (instead of Terminal) and use Terminal for interactive consoles.

In order to do that go into Terminal and open the settings. Under the Startup section the 2nd option lets you modify the launch-type for stand-alone scripts.
Changing that back to conhost should fix your problem.